# comparing specific lines in two files.txt using python

Tags: python, file, compare, txt

I'm writing this code to compare a log file and a reference file, however, the date is always causing a problem when comparing since the reference files are generated before the log.
I want to be able to compare specific lines not the whole file!
here is my code:

```
##HIL_Result =filecmp.cmp(f1, f2)
##print(HIL_Result)
f1=open(file1,'r')
f2=open(file2,'r')
for line1 in f1: 
    for line2 in f2: 
        if line1==line2: 
            print("SAME\n") 
        else: 
            print(line1 + line2) 
        break 
f1.close() 
f2.close()
```

Comment: instead of comparing full line compare the relevant part and exclude other as you mentioned date is casuing the issue

Comment: The way your current  for-loops are constructed, you will exhaust the file `f2` in the first loop of `f1`. Unless you reset `f2` to the start of the file again, the for-loop for it will not execute on the other loops of `f1`.

Comment: Could you please provide an example-input for `f1` and `f2`? In addition, please add the expected output from using those to files.

Answer (score 0):

This will go through every line of both files and compare them.

If one file has more lines than the other, it won't iterate over the extra lines in the longer file. Use `zip_longest(f1, f2, fillvalue="")` if you need to iterate over every line.

```py
filename1 = r"C:\file1.txt"
filename2 = r"C:\file2.txt"

with open(filename1) as f1, open(filename2) as f2:
    for i, (line1, line2) in enumerate(zip(f1, f2)):
        if line1 == line2:
            print(f"Line {i} is the same in both files.")
        else:
            print(f"Line {i} is different.")
```